# Magento2: is there a product list limit?

Tags: magento2

In an existing Magento2 shop I have a category that contains a lot of products (over 2000). But when I click on it, only the first 190 of them are shown. Is there any way to set that limit, and if so, where?

Or is there an other reason why my products list is limited to 190 products? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Used `setPageSize()` and `setCurPag‌​e()`

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

$data = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Product\Collection')->setPageSize(10)->setCurPag‌​e(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the 190 product form below script

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
/** Apply filters here */
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
$productCollection->setPageSize(190)
$productCollection->load();
```